# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "newAgStackInstance", compDetails is undefined

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

```
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
return {
  menuTabs: ["generalMenuTab"],
  editable: true,
  sortable: true,
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 100,
  filter: true,
  resizable: true,
  //This is the erroneous part
  headerComponent: CustomHeader,
};
}, []);
```

Is this syntax deprecated ? I can't find anything related to this in the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug, I'm getting a similar issue whenever I specify `headerComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `headerComponent` with `headerComponentFramework`. I'm guessing their documentation is just outdated

Comment: AG GRID v27+
All properties ending with the word 'Framework' are no longer needed.